# Selection.formula issue - VB Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

I"m attempting to create a sub that will update-correct the cell assignments for a large series of drop down controls (Excel) - to avoid having to do this manually.

Code (prior to creating loop - just trying to get one line to work...):

```
Dim StartIT, RowIT As Integer
RowIT = InputBox("Indicate the FIRST Row # to COPY... ")
StartIT = InputBox("Indicate the Current-HIGHEST Array Element # ")
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Drop Down " & StartIT)).Select
Selection.Formula = "=$J$" & CStr(RowIT)
```

Getting error on Selection.Formula line; "Object doesn't support this property or method".
i am a bit new to VB but this seems very basic and i have researched it.  Can't figure out how to make this work - Have tried quite a few variations.  Would greatly appreciate all input and direction.

Comment: Try `.LinkedCell` instead of `.Formula`

Comment: Is this a validation list? If so, try: `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Drop Down " & StartIT)).Validation.Modify Formula1:= "=$J$" & Cstr(RowIT)`

Comment: .LinkedCell worked fine.  Thankyou VERY much for the fast and helpful response.  Very much appreciated.